# Upload load big size file in PHP

Tags: php

I need to upload big size file by web page in PHP, as I surveyed, there are three variables related to upload.

- post_max_size=100MB
- upload_max_filesize=100MB
- memory_limit

If I want to upload file under 100 MB, is that right just set size to 100 MB? and how much should I give to memory_limit for 100 MB file; Is there any other issue may cause the file can't finished upload.

Comment: you have tested those values?

Comment: I need to give my rental hosting value, and they will set it for me, therefore I need to give them memory_limit as well,so I better make sure the accuracy to avoid too much revising.

Comment: add 30% to the max values for overhead and memory wont be an issue for the upload, php is not going to be putting the file in to memory.

Comment: post_max_size and upload_max_filesize all set to 130 MB, and leave memory_limit alone?

Comment: that's my call. If you want to trust random strangers on the internet ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The memory limit will be difficult because it depends on how you wish to process the file. If you're just going to write it to the disk without much processing, 100MB should be fine. If you're going to do any extensive processing on it, you may very well need to increase it higher depending on how your algorithm is handling memory usage.

Comment: It's a movie file, just upload to the disk, nothing more, how much memory should I set?